# Does anyone know a good tool for stress/load/performance testing for flash applications(windows based)?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5, unity-game-engine

basically i am asking for the tool which can help me in testing of a flash application(flash games). it may be a server based game developed in Unity 3D or openspace or Actionscript.
Tool should be for performance/ load testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [SWFWire Debugger](http://www.swfwire.com/debugger).  It should be able to help you find memory leaks and slow methods.  For stress testing, you probably need to write code specific to your app once you find weak points.

*Disclaimer: I wrote this app.*

Comment: thanks for your support. actually i am a manual tester and my company asked me to prepare a presentation on the "Use of Automation Tools in Game Testing". As all we know that the automation in Game Testing is tends to impossible. But yes we can use tools for Load/performance testing. I am testing flash games. I am exploring the tool "SWFWire Debugger". i will reply you as soon as possible if i face any difficulty......hoping for more support   Thanks

Comment: i just have an overview on "SWFWire Debugger" and i think this is for developers..... do you have any idea for the tool for the testers.....?

Answer (score 0):

Load testing usually deals with server load, not client load.  Most load testing tools have a recorder that will record your requests to the server which you can then play back to the server to simulate load.

Because of this, load testing tools don't tend to drive the client application directly.  Opening a browser and an instance of the Flash player is really expensive.  To simulate thousands of requests, it is better to just play back the requests to the server without an actual browser.

With that being said, most load testing tools don't actually care if your app was written in Flash, Silverlight or just HTML.  The important thing is that it can record the requests/responses to/from the server.